# rep cap was reached *only*

Tags: discussion, reputation

So, I looked at stackoverflow.com/reputation for the first time recently and I couldn't help but notice the word, `*only*` in:

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on <n> days

I was wondering, does this `*only*` disappear at some point? Or does Jon Skeet have

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 1460 days?

(That's right, that puts Jon Skeet at 124k rep before StackOverflow even started)

Comment: The best phrasing is probably placing *only* before *upvotes*.

Comment: I'd tag this `feature-request` or something -- this bothers me too.

Comment: I disagree with waiwai... This is the correct English phrasing. To place only before upvotes sounds strange, grammatically. If you *really* want to eliminate syntactic ambiguity, you would need to use parentheses. Just like most programming languages do in their formal grammars.

Comment: What about a couple of commas? `rep cap was reached, via rep from upvotes \*only\*, on <n> days`. That resolves ambiguity without resorting to parenthetical statements (which I always feel are more on the less formal side)

Comment: Yeah, okay. Commas would work. Little wanna-be parentheses. ;-)

Comment: @Cody NAY SIR! Commas are the life-breath of poetry! They are the source of context and meaning. They convey belonging, and, dare I say, communion with their surrounding words. Parenthesis, on the other hand, militantly oppose union with their compatriots, almost as if to say, "this piece of the sentence does not belong, but we will stand sentinel to prevent pollution from these lesser beings".

Comment: Suggest `rep cap was reached *solely* via rep from upvotes on <n> days`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sentence actually means:

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *alone* on <n> days

In other words:

> rep cap was reached via rep from 20+ upvotes on <n> days

Meaning you didn't need any accepted answers, etc in order to reach the cap; it was purely based on upvotes.

Technically your interpretation would have to be worded this way:

> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes on *only* <n> days

I don't blame you for misinterpreting, though, most people aren't very careful with the placement of words like that.

Comment: Yea... English... I love my native tongue, but it is seriously messed up.

Comment: Not necessarily 20 upvotes, if you also got downvotes.

Comment: Yes, this is an interesting statistic, but how is it relevant?  There is no badge related to it, like "Ballot Mortarboard".

Answer (score 4):

I think you're parsing the sentence wrong. I read it as

> The reputation cap was reached (via reputation which only came from upvotes) on 1460 days.

The "only" is referring to the fact that reputation from accepted answers and bounties is not counted, only reputation from upvotes.